# Query and print out random nodes in drupal

Tags: 6, theming, nodes

How to query random nodes in Drupal 6 without views?

I can print out last nodes but random nodes are the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure where you are doing this, but this would be one dull ax way of doing it:

```
$query=db_query('SELECT nid, RAND() as _random FROM {node} WHERE status = 1 ORDER BY _random ASC LIMIT 1');
$result=db_fetch_object($query);
```

and then you can do whatever you want with `$result->nid`, another dull ax:

```
drupal_goto('node/' . $result->nid);
```

or

```
$node=node_load($result->nid);
// do whatever you want with it
```

etc

Comment: The SQL can just be "SELECT nid FROM {node} WHERE status = 1 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1", unless you really need the random number back.